# Editting the first occurence of a pattern in the first uncommented line containing it

Tags: perl, shell

I'm trying to edit the first uncommented line only containing a pattern. Since there are several commented and uncommented similar lines I'm not able to edit only the first occurrence of it

Original:

```
#/app2/rsync_root:IP1:IP2:IP3:IP4
/app2/rsync_root:IP1:IP2:IP3:IP4
/app2/rsync_root:IP1:IP2:IP3:IP4
```

Expected result after editing:

```
#/app2/rsync_root:IP1:IP2:IP3:IP4
/app2/rsync_root:ipaddr1:ipaddr2:ipaddr3:ipaddr4
/app2/rsync_root:IP1:IP2:IP3:IP4
```

What is happening:

```
#/app2/rsync_root:IP1:IP2:IP3:IP4
/app2/rsync_root:ipaddr1:ipaddr2:ipaddr3:ipaddr4
/app2/rsync_root:ipaddr1:ipaddr2:ipaddr3:ipaddr4
```

I can just use the first colon from LHS as the delimiter as the field after can be anything.

Right now I'm using this command:

```
sed -ie '/^#/!s/:.*/:$ipaddr1:$ipaddr2:$ipaddr2:$ipaddr1/'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -pe'/^#/ or s/:\K.*/.../ .. 0'
```

or

```
perl -pe's/^(?!#)[^:]*:\K.*/.../ .. 0'
```

Comment: Sorry how do i use it?? Im new to perl can u be more specific pls?

Comment: It's just like `sed`. Takes from STDIN or provided file name. Outputs to STDOUT, or in-place if you use `-i`. `-i~` will make a backup.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using non-standard sed (`-i` is non standard), you may be able to simply add a `q` flag to your existing solution:

```
sed -ie '/^#/!s/:.*/:$ipaddr1:$ipaddr2:$ipaddr2:$ipaddr1/q'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
repl="ipaddr1:ipaddr2:ipaddr3:ipaddr4"
awk -v r="$repl" 'found==0 && !/^#/ {sub(/:.*/, ":" r); found=1} 1' file > new &&
mv new file
```

Answer (score 0):

Plain old `ed`

```
ed file << END
/^[^#]/s/:.*/:$ipaddr1:$ipaddr2:$ipaddr2:$ipaddr1/
w
q
END
```